# Скомпилированный файл отсутствует в целевой папке

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Собственно программа компилируется и пишет, что компиляция выполнена, но когда захожу в папку с проектом по пути, где должен быть файл, там ничего нет! Что с этим делать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте в VS режим Debug, после компиляции(F5), в папке с проектом появится папка "bin", а в ней "debug", там и будет exe-шник вашей проги.